# How to split string by string delimiter? Unexpected String.Split("<br>".ToCharArray()) behavior

Tags: c#, .net

I have input string like this (pasted from .NET debugger):

```
"g: 17.00 2D nap<br>\ng: 14.30 2D dub ; 17.15 3D nap<br>\ng: 14.30 3D dub ; 17.15 2D nap<br>\ng: 17.00 2D dub<br>\ng: 17.00 3D dub"
```

I'm trying to split it by `"<br>"`:

```
var items = mystring.Split("<br>".ToCharArray()); // 7 elements
```

I'm getting 7 list elements instead of 5.

It looks like `Split` function splits also by ";" separator.

For now I found workaround like this:

```
var items = mystring.Replace("<br>", "|").Split("|".ToCharArray()); // 5 elements
```

but what is going on?

Comment: You are splitting by chars found in <br>, not a complete <br> string. Try regex.split instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue is in the use of `ToCharArray()`.

The `String.Split()` overload that takes a `char[]`, which you're using, will use each individual character as a delimiter: therefore, by passing in `"<br>".ToCharArray()`, which gives the constituent characters of `<br>`, you're splitting your string by any of `<`, `b`, `r` or `>`, which you'll agree is not what you want.

Now, there isn't an overload for splitting by a single string with no options, but it's pretty easy to circumvent this:

```
var items = mystring.Split(new[] { "<br>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RegEx.Split`

```
var items = RegEx.Split(mystring, "<br>");
```

This will split on exact matches of `<br>` and not split on the characters individually as said in other answers.